# How to send automated emails that don't get marked as spam?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

My PHP server is sending verification emails when customers sign up, so that they can verify their email address.

But sometimes gmail automatically disables less-secure apps, and I have to go into the settings and re-enable it so that phpmailer can connect again.

Also, the emails get through for a while and then show up as spam.

Is there some more modern/standard way of doing automatic emails for this purpose? I feel like phpmailer isn't working for me.

Does Google have some simple API where I can just pass the recipient address and the message body?

Comment: I am using phpmailer with SMTP verification, gmail can detect when does the email comes from a php script which can be considered spam, or is it coming from SMTP with TLS encryption. This may help.

Comment: It’s not really anything to with the fact that you’re using PHPMailer, but PHPMailer’s wiki has advice about how to go about avoiding spam filters. Be warned though – it is difficult, unreliable, and frustrating for *everyone* trying to send legitimately.